# How to set the referrer in an _integration_ test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Rspec can't access the HTTP referrer.

My `user_sessions#create` action contains: `redirect_to :back`, which Rails can only execute by reading the HTTP referrer.

Stackoverflow contains plenty of posts about how to set/mock/whatever the referrer in a *controller* spec. The general vibe is `request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] = etc etc`.

But I need `redirect_to :back` to work in an *integration* test that looks like this:

```
click_link "login"
page.current_path.should == "/login"
fill_in "user_session_email", :with => @user.email
fill_in "user_session_password", :with => @user.password
click_on "submit_user_session"
page.current_path.should == new_order_path
click_on "submit_order"
```

How can I do this?

Bonus points if the solution tells this spec to store the referral for every URL it visits (so the test is robust) and has no impact on other specs (for speed).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Capybara.current_session.driver.header 'Referer', 'http://example.com'
```

It looks like you're using [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara), you can use Capybara to explicitly set the referer.  You would have to update it whenever you wanted it to change, and if you needed to remove it you could set it to `nil`.

Maybe a bit cleaner:

```
referer = 'http://example.com'
Capybara.current_session.driver.header 'Referer', referer
```

Comment: Thanks. `Capybara.current_session.driver.header 'Referer', page.current_path` just before `click_link "login"` worked a treat.

Comment: How so?  Is page.current_path not nil?

Comment: Sorry I hit submit on that comment too early. I've got it working now. I'll submit the working version in a moment.

Comment: The working code is...

in spec_helper.rb:

`Capybara.server_port = 4000`

(Obviously pick a different port if you are an ICQ user.)

In the integration test:

`store_path = "http://localhost:4000#{page.current_path}"`
`click_link "login"`
 `Capybara.current_session.driver.header 'Referer', store_path`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code used to implement the [redirect_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/redirect_to) method:

```
if referer = request.headers["Referer"]
  redirect_to(referer, :status=>status)
else
  raise RedirectBackError
end
```

Have you tried to set `request.headers['Referer']` directly ?

Comment: This seems like the right path.
If only our answers could be combined. . .